# pgfplots: color a surf using arbitrary colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab

I am trying to figure out if there is an equivalent in pgfplots to what in MATLAB is done through the following command: `surf(A,B)`. This would plot the geometry `A`, using the colors specified in `B`.

I am using the script from [here](http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/) to convert a few MATLAB plots to `pgfplots`, but the script ignores the second parameter of plot and exports only the values used for geometry. Hence, pgfplots plots `A` using the default `jetmap`, and I would like it to be colored using the values in `B`.

Here is what I get using `pgfplots`

[image]

and this is how I want it to look

[image]

Any guess?

Cheers.

EDIT: The code I am using so far is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={64}{26},
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=1, xmax=11,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=1, ymax=11,
ymajorgrids,
zmin=275, zmax=320,
zmajorgrids,
axis lines=left,
grid=none,
point meta min=0, point meta max=1
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
draw=black]
coordinates{ 
(1,1,317.78006)(1,2,313.597321)(1,3,309.414581)(1,4,305.231842)(1,5,301.049103)(1,6,296.866364)(1,7,295.766754)(1,8,294.667145)(1,9,293.567566)(1,10,292.467957)(1,11,291.368347)

(2,1,313.520264)(2,2,309.469849)(2,3,305.419434)(2,4,301.369019)(2,5,297.318604)(2,6,293.268188)(2,7,292.487549)(2,8,291.70694)(2,9,290.926331)(2,10,290.145691)(2,11,289.365082)

(3,1,309.260498)(3,2,305.342407)(3,3,301.424316)(3,4,297.506226)(3,5,293.588104)(3,6,289.670013)(3,7,289.208374)(3,8,288.746735)(3,9,288.285095)(3,10,287.823425)(3,11,287.361816)

(4,1,305.000702)(4,2,301.214905)(4,3,297.429138)(4,4,293.643372)(4,5,289.857605)(4,6,286.071838)(4,7,285.929169)(4,8,285.786499)(4,9,285.64386)(4,10,285.50119)(4,11,285.358521)

(5,1,300.740936)(5,2,297.087463)(5,3,293.434021)(5,4,289.780579)(5,5,286.127106)(5,6,282.473663)(5,7,282.649963)(5,8,282.826294)(5,9,283.002594)(5,10,283.178925)(5,11,283.355225)

(6,1,296.48114)(6,2,292.959991)(6,3,289.438873)(6,4,285.917755)(6,5,282.396606)(6,6,278.875488)(6,7,279.370789)(6,8,279.866089)(6,9,280.361359)(6,10,280.856659)(6,11,281.351959)

(7,1,294.19873)(7,2,291.054535)(7,3,287.910339)(7,4,284.766144)(7,5,281.621918)(7,6,278.477753)(7,7,279.38205)(7,8,280.286346)(7,9,281.190613)(7,10,282.09494)(7,11,282.999237)

(8,1,291.916321)(8,2,289.149048)(8,3,286.381805)(8,4,283.614532)(8,5,280.84726)(8,6,278.079987)(8,7,279.393311)(8,8,280.706604)(8,9,282.019897)(8,10,283.333191)(8,11,284.646515)

(9,1,289.633942)(9,2,287.243591)(9,3,284.853241)(9,4,282.462921)(9,5,280.072571)(9,6,277.682251)(9,7,279.404541)(9,8,281.126862)(9,9,282.849152)(9,10,284.571472)(9,11,286.293762)

(10,1,287.351532)(10,2,285.338104)(10,3,283.324707)(10,4,281.31131)(10,5,279.297913)(10,6,277.284485)(10,7,279.415802)(10,8,281.547119)(10,9,283.678436)(10,10,285.809723)(10,11,287.94104)

(11,1,285.069122)(11,2,283.432648)(11,3,281.796173)(11,4,280.159698)(11,5,278.523224)(11,6,276.886749)(11,7,279.427063)(11,8,281.967377)(11,9,284.50769)(11,10,287.048004)(11,11,289.588318)

};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And these are the values I want to use to color up this thing:

```
 0.0037    0.0294    0.0435    0.0448    0.0313         0    0.0612    0.0923    0.0943    0.0652    0.0037
    0.0308    0.0677    0.0908    0.0985    0.0878    0.0550    0.1244    0.1616    0.1675    0.1404    0.0790
    0.0473    0.0943    0.1248    0.1364    0.1251    0.0871    0.1623    0.2032    0.2111    0.1842    0.1207
    0.0509    0.1067    0.1424    0.1544    0.1384    0.0924    0.1707    0.2133    0.2212    0.1924    0.1250
    0.0385    0.1011    0.1387    0.1466    0.1228    0.0663    0.1454    0.1879    0.1939    0.1615    0.0884
    0.0048    0.0717    0.1067    0.1069    0.0726    0.0036    0.0819    0.1225    0.1251    0.0874    0.0060
    0.1147    0.1927    0.2320    0.2329    0.1967    0.1242    0.2019    0.2407    0.2399    0.1963    0.1072
    0.1840    0.2703    0.3132    0.3141    0.2755    0.1979    0.2733    0.3088    0.3030    0.2537    0.1594
    0.1956    0.2870    0.3337    0.3363    0.2958    0.2129    0.2856    0.3169    0.3068    0.2544    0.1613
    0.1359    0.2267    0.2746    0.2789    0.2384    0.1534    0.2255    0.2556    0.2454    0.1967    0.1115
    0.0037    0.0878    0.1306    0.1317    0.0900    0.0042    0.0802    0.1157    0.1131    0.0754    0.0037
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, pgfplots can do it: you can provide color data explicitly.

I suppose the most simple way is to provide a combined table with columns x y z c and to tell pgfplots

1. to read point meta data which is given explicitly `point meta=explicit`
2. to configure from where explicit color data should be read `\addplot .. table[meta=c]` .

You can generate such data files in matlab using `data = [ A(:) B(:) ]` (or something like that).

Here is your example (hopefully correctly concatenated):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm}

\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty}%--- CF

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={64}{26},
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=1, xmax=11,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=1, ymax=11,
ymajorgrids,
zmin=275, zmax=320,
zmajorgrids,
axis lines=left,
grid=none,
point meta min=0, point meta max=1,
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
colormap/jet,
shader=faceted,
point meta=explicit, % ---- CF
draw=black]
table[meta=c]{ % ---- CF
    x   y   z           c
    1   1   317.78006   0.0037
    1   2   313.597321  0.0294
    1   3   309.414581  0.0435
    1   4   305.231842  0.0448
    1   5   301.049103  0.0313
    1   6   296.866364  0
    1   7   295.766754  0.0612
    1   8   294.667145  0.0923
    1   9   293.567566  0.0943
    1   10  292.467957  0.0652
    1   11  291.368347  0.0037

    2   1   313.520264  0.0308
    2   2   309.469849  0.0677
    2   3   305.419434  0.0908
    2   4   301.369019  0.0985
    2   5   297.318604  0.0878
    2   6   293.268188  0.0550
    2   7   292.487549  0.1244
    2   8   291.70694   0.1616
    2   9   290.926331  0.1675
    2   10  290.145691  0.1404
    2   11  289.365082  0.0790

    3   1   309.260498  0.0473
    3   2   305.342407  0.0943
    3   3   301.424316  0.1248
    3   4   297.506226  0.1364
    3   5   293.588104  0.1251
    3   6   289.670013  0.0871
    3   7   289.208374  0.1623
    3   8   288.746735  0.2032
    3   9   288.285095  0.2111
    3   10  287.823425  0.1842
    3   11  287.361816  0.1207

    4   1   305.000702  0.0509
    4   2   301.214905  0.1067
    4   3   297.429138  0.1424
    4   4   293.643372  0.1544
    4   5   289.857605  0.1384
    4   6   286.071838  0.0924
    4   7   285.929169  0.1707
    4   8   285.786499  0.2133
    4   9   285.64386   0.2212
    4   10  285.50119   0.1924
    4   11  285.358521  0.1250

    5   1   300.740936  0.0385
    5   2   297.087463  0.1011
    5   3   293.434021  0.1387
    5   4   289.780579  0.1466
    5   5   286.127106  0.1228
    5   6   282.473663  0.0663
    5   7   282.649963  0.1454
    5   8   282.826294  0.1879
    5   9   283.002594  0.1939
    5   10  283.178925  0.1615
    5   11  283.355225  0.0884

    6   1   296.48114   0.0048
    6   2   292.959991  0.0717
    6   3   289.438873  0.1067
    6   4   285.917755  0.1069
    6   5   282.396606  0.0726
    6   6   278.875488  0.0036
    6   7   279.370789  0.0819
    6   8   279.866089  0.1225
    6   9   280.361359  0.1251
    6   10  280.856659  0.0874
    6   11  281.351959  0.0060

    7   1   294.19873   0.1147
    7   2   291.054535  0.1927
    7   3   287.910339  0.2320
    7   4   284.766144  0.2329
    7   5   281.621918  0.1967
    7   6   278.477753  0.1242
    7   7   279.38205   0.2019
    7   8   280.286346  0.2407
    7   9   281.190613  0.2399
    7   10  282.09494   0.1963
    7   11  282.999237  0.1072

    8   1   291.916321  0.1840
    8   2   289.149048  0.2703
    8   3   286.381805  0.3132
    8   4   283.614532  0.3141
    8   5   280.84726   0.2755
    8   6   278.079987  0.1979
    8   7   279.393311  0.2733
    8   8   280.706604  0.3088
    8   9   282.019897  0.3030
    8   10  283.333191  0.2537
    8   11  284.646515  0.1594

    9   1   289.633942  0.1956
    9   2   287.243591  0.2870
    9   3   284.853241  0.3337
    9   4   282.462921  0.3363
    9   5   280.072571  0.2958
    9   6   277.682251  0.2129
    9   7   279.404541  0.2856
    9   8   281.126862  0.3169
    9   9   282.849152  0.3068
    9   10  284.571472  0.2544
    9   11  286.293762  0.1613

    10  1   287.351532  0.1359
    10  2   285.338104  0.2267
    10  3   283.324707  0.2746
    10  4   281.31131   0.2789
    10  5   279.297913  0.2384
    10  6   277.284485  0.1534
    10  7   279.415802  0.2255
    10  8   281.547119  0.2556
    10  9   283.678436  0.2454
    10  10  285.809723  0.1967
    10  11  287.94104   0.1115

    11  1   285.069122  0.0037
    11  2   283.432648  0.0878
    11  3   281.796173  0.1306
    11  4   280.159698  0.1317
    11  5   278.523224  0.0900
    11  6   276.886749  0.0042
    11  7   279.427063  0.0802
    11  8   281.967377  0.1157
    11  9   284.50769   0.1131
    11  10  287.048004  0.0754
    11  11  289.588318  0.0037
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey Christian, this is awesome! Thanks a lot! The colour maps were generating normalising a set of errors I got. Each vertex of this surface has got an error value, and this is what I want to use to colour the surface, so I normalised these errors in [0, 1]. However, in this particular example the errors are pretty low, that's why all values are fairly low. I only have one further question, how can I force the colormap to be in the range [0, 1], so this surface will look all blue-ish (as the example I pasted in my question)? So far,the color map is being "re-normalised" using the given range.

Comment: Oh! Regarding your question, to generate this color map in MATLAB I used the following code: figure;
surf(b04_07_pieceWise,1-normErrorsPiceWise);
xlim([1 11]);
ylim([1 11]);
zlim([275 320]);
rotate3d;
axis(gca,'vis3d');
caxis([0 1]);
The trick here is in the line "caxis([0 1])", which forces the range of the colormap to be 0..1 and not the actual range of the used values.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my answer - and I will fix the bug in pgfplots.

Comment: Silly me -- there is only a bug if you use `meta=z`. No matter, I will fix it. I have removed the misleading bug warning.

Comment: Cheer Christian, awesome support!

Comment: @Dan please check if my linearization lead to a transposed color data matrix before you start to use it... it seems transposed.

Comment: Yes Chris, I took that into account. Numbers were transposed, but what matters it that it can actually be done. I wrote a MATLAB script that creates and stores the correct matrix. Took a while to figure out the whole thing, but now looks awesome. Thanks a lot!