# 2D colors above 3D surface plot

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I would like to draw a 2D, colored plot of a function above its surface plot.

I tried copying the surface plot and setting `z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{1.4}}`, but then everything is the same color on the 2D plot.

Also, I'd be glad if I could avoid the antialiasing artifacts on the 2D plot (each quad is made of two triangles, and there is a small white line between them).

[image: Surface plot below, 2D plot above]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both]
    \addplot3[
    surf,
    shader=faceted interp,
    samples=10,
    ] {sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))};

    \addplot3[
    surf,
    shader=faceted interp,
    samples=10,
    z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{1.4}}
    ] {sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related : [pgfplots: color a surf using arbitrary colors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56420/5699). I found it after the answer was posted here, while searching for something totally different :) .

Comment: The triangulation (quad->triangles) is actually a bug in some older version of pgfplots, not some kind of viewing artifact. It was (only) present for `shader=faceted interp`. It has been fixed in the meantime; an upgrade to the current stable version will eliminate it.

Comment: Just a side note: highly oscillating functions like yours involve a relatively high resolution in order to look smooth. A potentially interesting alternative is to use `\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}` and add the two options `patch type=bicubic, patch type sampling,` to your surface plot. This will cause a much smoother surface. Works only with plot-by-expression, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The color of the plot depends on the `meta` value, which by default, is the `z` value in 3D plots. You can set it to something else, however: In this case, you'd say `point meta={sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))}` (so you'd use the original function for the meta value), and simply plot `{1.4}` instead of the function:

[image]

About the artifacts: That's probably a viewer issue. I don't see them using Adobe Reader or Evince on Ubuntu Linux.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both]
    \addplot3[
    surf,
    shader=faceted interp,
    samples=10,
    ] {sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))};

    \addplot3[
    surf,
    shader=faceted interp,
    samples=10,point meta rel=per plot,
    point meta={sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))}
    ] {1.4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My viewer is also evince, under ubuntu. Oh well… Could you please post the code for your answer?

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron: Sorry, forgot about that. Question is edited.

Comment: @Jake, I'm getting errors: `pgfkeys: Choice '1.7' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors'. I am going to ignore this key. \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}` and others.

Comment: @Sigur: Then you're probably using a version of PGFPlots older than 1.7. Just use `compat=newest`.

Comment: @Jake, one less error but now the error is `pgfkeys: Choice 'faceted interp' unknown in key '/pgfplots/shader'. I am going to ignore this key. ...amples=10,] {sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))};` I guess that I should try to install pfgplots again.

Comment: @Sigur otherwise just use one of the following for the `shader=` key : `flat`, `flat corner`, `interp`, `facetted`, `facetted interp` (There are a few more I think, check the documentation), or just remove that key. `facetted` gives the "lines" you see between the pathces, and interp makes the patches colored by a gradient, instead of having a single color. But yes, you should upgrade your `pgfplots` package :) .

Comment: I am new to pgfplots so please excuse me if this question is very simplistic! I just wanted to know that If instead of a function I have point values (in a separate file) how can I add the 2D surface on top? I have already successfully drawn my 3D plot data, but I would like to add a 2D surface like the samples here. I would really appreciate any help. What part of this code has to be changed to what?

Comment: @astroboy: You should open a new question for this that includes a small example document demonstrating how you plot the 3D surface.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the question is posted in this address: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103023/2d-surface-on-a-3d-surface-plot-external-data-in-a-file