# 2D surface on a 3D surface plot external data in a file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks, 3d

I am drawing a 3D surface from external data. Here they are:

```
0 0 -0.64
1 0 -0.5
2 0 -0.4
3 0 -0.31
4 0 -0.23
5 0 -0.2
6 0 -0.24
7 0 -0.32
8 0 -0.42
9 0 -0.59
10 0 -0.76

0 1 -0.54
1 1 -0.4
2 1 -0.27
3 1 -0.17
4 1 -0.08
5 1 -0.03
6 1 -0.05
7 1 -0.14
8 1 -0.27
9 1 -0.45
10 1 -0.63

0 2 -0.46
1 2 -0.31
2 2 -0.16
3 2 -0.03
4 2 0.07
5 2 0.12
6 2 0.11
7 2 0.02
8 2 -0.13
9 2 -0.32
10 2 -0.51

0 3 -0.44
1 3 -0.26
2 3 -0.08
3 3 0.07
4 3 0.18
5 3 0.25
6 3 0.24
7 3 0.14
8 3 -0.01
9 3 -0.2
10 3 -0.41

0 4 -0.44
1 4 -0.26
2 4 -0.04
3 4 0.13
4 4 0.25
5 4 0.32
6 4 0.31
7 4 0.22
8 4 0.07
9 4 -0.14
10 4 -0.37

0 5 -0.44
1 5 -0.26
2 5 -0.05
3 5 0.14
4 5 0.27
5 5 0.34
6 5 0.33
7 5 0.24
8 5 0.09
9 5 -0.12
10 5 -0.36

0 6 -0.48
1 6 -0.29
2 6 -0.08
3 6 0.09
4 6 0.22
5 6 0.29
6 6 0.28
7 6 0.2
8 6 0.06
9 6 -0.13
10 6 -0.35

0 7 -0.55
1 7 -0.34
2 7 -0.15
3 7 -0.0
4 7 0.11
5 7 0.18
6 7 0.18
7 7 0.11
8 7 -0.02
9 7 -0.2
10 7 -0.39

0 8 -0.63
1 8 -0.44
2 8 -0.27
3 8 -0.13
4 8 -0.03
5 8 0.04
6 8 0.04
7 8 -0.02
8 8 -0.13
9 8 -0.29
10 8 -0.45

0 9 -0.71
1 9 -0.59
2 9 -0.43
3 9 -0.28
4 9 -0.18
5 9 -0.13
6 9 -0.13
7 9 -0.17
8 9 -0.26
9 9 -0.38
10 9 -0.53

0 10 -0.83
1 10 -0.75
2 10 -0.59
3 10 -0.45
4 10 -0.35
5 10 -0.3
6 10 -0.3
7 10 -0.34
8 10 -0.42
9 10 -0.52
10 10 -0.66
```

I am using the following code to plot it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={-20}{20}, grid=both]
      \addplot3[surf] file {filename.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can see the result bellow:
[image: Result of the code:]

I want to know how I can add a 2D surface on top of this like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/2d-colors-above-3d-surface-plot). So the only difference I feel is that I have external data instead of a function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I ask you how you have generated the values for the plot? I think it is not out of head?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The approach for adding a flat surface with the colour representing a data column is quite similar to that in the question you linked to.

You have to set the `z` value of the plot to a constant value, and use the `meta` value to represent the colour information. For this, you have to use the `table` plot style (instead of `file`), you need to set `point meta=explicit` in the `\addplot` options so PGFPlots knows not to use the `z` value for the `meta` value, and you have to put `z expr=<come constant value>, meta index=2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{filename.txt}
0 0 -0.64
1 0 -0.5
2 0 -0.4
3 0 -0.31
4 0 -0.23
5 0 -0.2
6 0 -0.24
7 0 -0.32
8 0 -0.42
9 0 -0.59
10 0 -0.76

0 1 -0.54
1 1 -0.4
2 1 -0.27
3 1 -0.17
4 1 -0.08
5 1 -0.03
6 1 -0.05
7 1 -0.14
8 1 -0.27
9 1 -0.45
10 1 -0.63

0 2 -0.46
1 2 -0.31
2 2 -0.16
3 2 -0.03
4 2 0.07
5 2 0.12
6 2 0.11
7 2 0.02
8 2 -0.13
9 2 -0.32
10 2 -0.51

0 3 -0.44
1 3 -0.26
2 3 -0.08
3 3 0.07
4 3 0.18
5 3 0.25
6 3 0.24
7 3 0.14
8 3 -0.01
9 3 -0.2
10 3 -0.41

0 4 -0.44
1 4 -0.26
2 4 -0.04
3 4 0.13
4 4 0.25
5 4 0.32
6 4 0.31
7 4 0.22
8 4 0.07
9 4 -0.14
10 4 -0.37

0 5 -0.44
1 5 -0.26
2 5 -0.05
3 5 0.14
4 5 0.27
5 5 0.34
6 5 0.33
7 5 0.24
8 5 0.09
9 5 -0.12
10 5 -0.36

0 6 -0.48
1 6 -0.29
2 6 -0.08
3 6 0.09
4 6 0.22
5 6 0.29
6 6 0.28
7 6 0.2
8 6 0.06
9 6 -0.13
10 6 -0.35

0 7 -0.55
1 7 -0.34
2 7 -0.15
3 7 -0.0
4 7 0.11
5 7 0.18
6 7 0.18
7 7 0.11
8 7 -0.02
9 7 -0.2
10 7 -0.39

0 8 -0.63
1 8 -0.44
2 8 -0.27
3 8 -0.13
4 8 -0.03
5 8 0.04
6 8 0.04
7 8 -0.02
8 8 -0.13
9 8 -0.29
10 8 -0.45

0 9 -0.71
1 9 -0.59
2 9 -0.43
3 9 -0.28
4 9 -0.18
5 9 -0.13
6 9 -0.13
7 9 -0.17
8 9 -0.26
9 9 -0.38
10 9 -0.53

0 10 -0.83
1 10 -0.75
2 10 -0.59
3 10 -0.45
4 10 -0.35
5 10 -0.3
6 10 -0.3
7 10 -0.34
8 10 -0.42
9 10 -0.52
10 10 -0.66
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={-20}{20}, grid=both]
      \addplot3[surf] file {filename.txt};
      \addplot3[surf, point meta=explicit] table [z expr=0.5, meta index=2] {filename.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to know if tikz/pgfplots is using gnuplot from the `.tex` source ? when do we use explicit gnuplot commands like in [PGFPLOTS](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41669/15717) ?.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explanation! It is only 3 days I am using pgfplots and I have a lot to learn. Thank you.

Comment: @texenthusiast: `gnuplot` is only used if the `gnuplot` plot handler is used (`\addplot gnuplot {...};`). I don't understand the second question in your comment: This is PGFPlots, and gnuplot commands are only used when the `gnuplot` keyword is used.

Comment: @Jake In [TeXample.net example](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/gnuplot-basics.tex) there is no `\addplot gnuplot{}` handler, but it says gnuplot required. How to confirm whether `.tex` source needs gnuplot ?

Comment: @Jake my second question is: when do we use explicitly  `\addplot gnuplot{}` commands vs `pgfmath` engine?

Comment: @texenthusiast: That example uses `\addplot function`, which is an alias for `\addplot gnuplot`. So whenever there's either `\addplot function` or `\addplot gnuplot`, the `gnuplot` backend is used. It's necessary to use `gnuplot` if the function you're trying to plot is too complicated for `pgfmath`.

Comment: @Jake Thanks a lot. Should we use Tikz or pgfplots to call gnuplot ? Which is better for larger data ? Is downsampling for large dataset done via gnuplot and on what basis ?

Comment: @texenthusiast: Whether you use TikZ of PGFPlots to call `gnuplot` depends on whether you want to use PGFPlots' features to generate the axes, legend, labels and colour bars. For large data, `gnuplot` is better than `pgfmath`, but it doesn't matter much whether you use plain TikZ or PGFPlots. Downsampling can be done using `gnuplot` but it doesn't happen automatically. See [pgfplot: plotting a large dataset](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71488/pgfplot-plotting-a-large-dataset) for an example of how to downsample a large dataset.

Comment: @Jake Thanks a lot for all your comments. Last Question : if i had to submit my `.tex` to journal editor(where if gnuplot may not be available), is there any possibility to strip out (tikzpicture environment) to get annotated-figure.pdf with `pdflatex -shell-escape` runs. Does `standalone` does it ?

Comment: @texenthusiast: You can simply use the `external` library that ships with TikZ: It creates separate `pdf` files for all your `tikzpicture` environments that can then simply be embedded using `\includegraphics`