# Algerian flag in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a code in Tikz of Algerian flag, anyone can help me to make it seems like flying flag?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.8]
\definecolor{dgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0};
\draw[draw=none,fill=dgreen] (-9.3,-5.5) rectangle (-1.1,5.5) ;
\draw[color=red, fill=dred,scale=1] (0:1.309)--(36:0.5) --
(72:1.309)--  (108:0.5)--(144:1.309)--(180:0.5)
--(216:1.309)--(252:0.5)--(288:1.309)--(324:0.5)--cycle;
\draw[color=gray,very thick] (-9.28,-5.51) --(7,-5.51)--(7,5.5) ;
\draw[color=gray] (7,5.5)--(-1.1,5.5) ;
\draw[draw=none,fill=dred] (50:2) arc (44:316:2.2cm) -- 
(310:2) arc (326:34:2.75cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57668/drawing-a-flag-with-tikz

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try a non-linear transform. They can be a bit tricky to work with, but if you work in points rather than centimetres and don't scale the coordinate system, specifying the transform as a function becomes easier, and the results can be quite satisfying:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\definecolor{deep green}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{deep red}{RGB}{200,0,0}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\def\fluttertransform{%
\pgfgetlastxy\x\y
\pgfpoint{\x+sin(\y)*10}{\y+sin(\x)*(36-\x/10)+\x/10}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\begin{scope}
\pgftransformnonlinear{\fluttertransform}
\fill [deep green] (0,0) rectangle (180,270);
\draw [gray] (0,0) rectangle (360,270);
\fill [deep red, shift={(180,135)}]
  (45:75) arc (45:315:75) arc (300:60:60 and 61);
\fill [deep red, shift={(210,135)}, rotate=5]
  (90:15) \foreach \i in {1,...,10} { 
    -- (90+\i*36:{mod(\i,2)*25+15})
  } -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Nice one, have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185018/how-can-i-represent-the-curved-shape-of-a-surface/278214#278214): I'll now look deeper into `nonlineartransformations`, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

This what I am looking for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\definecolor{dgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0};
\definecolor{dred}{RGB}{215,0,0};
\definecolor{MainRed}{rgb}{.6, .1, .1}
\definecolor{GoldDecoration}{RGB}{170, 120, 70}
\begin{scope}[rotate=0]
 \draw[left color=GoldDecoration] (-.1,0) to [bend right]     
  (.1,0)-- (.1,8) to [bend left] (-.1,8) -- cycle;
  \draw[ball color=GoldDecoration] (0,8) circle (.2) ;
  \begin{scope}
     \draw [clip,rounded corners] (.1,7.6) to [out=60 ,in=180]
     coordinate[pos=.95] (h1) (3,8) to [out=0, in = 200]
      coordinate[pos=.5] (h2) (8,9) coordinate(h3) to [out=-85 ,in=85] 
      (7.5,4) coordinate(b3) to [out=220,in=0]
       coordinate[pos=.85] (b2)(5,3)  to [out=180,in=10]
       coordinate[pos=.5] (b1)(.1,3) to [out =85,in=-80]  (.1,7.6) ;
      \fill[dgreen] (0,8.5) -- (4.35,8.35) to[out=-89,in=80] 
      (4.3,3) -- (0,3) --cycle;
  \end{scope}
\draw[thick,MainRed] [rounded corners] (.1,7.6) to [out=60 ,in=180]
 coordinate[pos=.95] (h1) (3,8) to[out=0, in = 200]
      coordinate[pos=.5] (h2) (8,9) coordinate(h3) to [out=-85 ,in=85] 
      (7.5,4) coordinate(b3) to [out=220,in=0]
      coordinate[pos=.85] (b2)(5,3)  to [out=180,in=10] 
     coordinate[pos=.5] (b1)(.1,3) to[out =85,in=-80]  (.1,7.6) ;
 \begin{scope}[shift={(4.95,5.5)}]
      \fill[dred] (50:0.9) arc (42.918:316:1.0125cm) -- (310:0.9) arc
     (326:33:1.2375cm);
       \fill[dred] (0:0.58905)--(36:0.225) -- (72:0.58905)--(108:0.225)--
        (144:0.58905)--(180:0.225)--(216:0.58905)--(252:0.225)--
        (288:0.58905)--(324:0.225)--cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Algerian flag]