# How to fading color the curve grid

Tags: foreach, control, tikz-fadings

I want to draw the curve grid as bellow picture.

Please help me control the grid with the belly and fade the color.

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {3,3.5,...,10.5}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xb}{0.4-0.05*\j}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yb}{11-0.01*\j}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xc}{7-0.3*\j}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\opa}{100-0.5*\j}
  
  \draw[thick,cyan!\opa] (\i,27) .. controls +(270:6) and +(80:4.5)..
     (\xb,\yb)..controls +(260:4.5) and +(75:4.6)..(\xc,0);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Update 5/11/2021, the code with rainbow color

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}   
\def\n{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\j] \i in {3,3.5,...,10.5}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xb}{0.4-0.05*\j}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yb}{11-0.01*\j}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xc}{7-0.3*\j}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\opa}{100-0.5*\j}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\faktor}{(\j-1)*400/\n+350}
          \definecolor{rainbow}{wave}{\faktor}
          \draw[ultra thick,rainbow] (\i,27) .. controls +(270:6) and +(80:4.5)..
                   (\xb,\yb)..controls +(260:4.5) and +(75:4.6)..(\xc,0);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275619 can help you.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your suggestion. My code has already used this technique. However, this image is different.

Answer (score 2):

With yours code modified like this one:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach[count=\j] \i in {3,3.5,...,10.5}{
             \pgfmathsetmacro{\xb}{0.4-0.05*\j}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yb}{11-0.01*\j}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xc}{7-0.3*\j}     
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{int(\j*100/16)}
            \draw[thick,cyan!\k] (\i,27) .. controls +(270:6) and +(80:4.5)..
            (\xb,\yb)..controls +(260:4.5) and +(75:4.6)..(\xc,0);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you have this result:

[image]

Comment: +1 why do the lines seem circular at the lower part of the intersection

Comment: Moiré pattern. People one this site upload low-resolution screenshots to favor visitors with slow internet.

Comment: @Nam Tran Le Your question was on fading colors non on rainbow. My answer, with a little correction of your first code, is for fading colors.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Fading along a line sir. I think that the original picture is also fading a long the curve.