# Color coded plots with colorbar in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

In matlab I can achieve this result using the structure of this minimal working example (in matlab):

```
figure('color','white'); hold on
xx=0:1;
colors = parula(5);
for i = 1:5
    color = colors(i,:);
    plot(xx, xx*i, 'color', color);
end
h = colorbar('Ticks',0:0.25:1,'TickLabels',{'1','2','3','4','5'});
h.Label.String = 'line slope';
```

which produce this:

[image]

I would like to do the same in pgfplots but i really don't know hot to do it!

For the curves I surely would load the data from tables, but for the color code and color bar I have no idea.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took a parula scale written by [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228241) and defined the `colormap` to use it. The curves are plotted with a for-each loop. I set the meta data of the points to the slope variable. The option `mesh` plots the lines with the colour of its meta data.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.11
    ,colormap={parula}{%
        rgb=(0.2081,0.1663,0.5292)rgb=(0.2116,0.1898,0.5777)rgb=(0.2123,0.2138,0.627)
        rgb=(0.2081,0.2386,0.6771)rgb=(0.1959,0.2645,0.7279)rgb=(0.1707,0.2919,0.7792)
        rgb=(0.1253,0.3242,0.8303)rgb=(0.0591,0.3598,0.8683)rgb=(0.0117,0.3875,0.882)
        rgb=(0.006,0.4086,0.8828) rgb=(0.0165,0.4266,0.8786)rgb=(0.0329,0.443,0.872)
        rgb=(0.0498,0.4586,0.8641)rgb=(0.0629,0.4737,0.8554)rgb=(0.0723,0.4887,0.8467)
        rgb=(0.0779,0.504,0.8384) rgb=(0.0793,0.52,0.8312)  rgb=(0.0749,0.5375,0.8263)
        rgb=(0.0641,0.557,0.824)  rgb=(0.0488,0.5772,0.8228)rgb=(0.0343,0.5966,0.8199)
        rgb=(0.0265,0.6137,0.8135)rgb=(0.0239,0.6287,0.8038)rgb=(0.0231,0.6418,0.7913)
        rgb=(0.0228,0.6535,0.7768)rgb=(0.0267,0.6642,0.7607)rgb=(0.0384,0.6743,0.7436)
        rgb=(0.059,0.6838,0.7254) rgb=(0.0843,0.6928,0.7062)rgb=(0.1133,0.7015,0.6859)
        rgb=(0.1453,0.7098,0.6646)rgb=(0.1801,0.7177,0.6424)rgb=(0.2178,0.725,0.6193)
        rgb=(0.2586,0.7317,0.5954)rgb=(0.3022,0.7376,0.5712)rgb=(0.3482,0.7424,0.5473)
        rgb=(0.3953,0.7459,0.5244)rgb=(0.442,0.7481,0.5033) rgb=(0.4871,0.7491,0.484)
        rgb=(0.53,0.7491,0.4661)  rgb=(0.5709,0.7485,0.4494)rgb=(0.6099,0.7473,0.4337)
        rgb=(0.6473,0.7456,0.4188)rgb=(0.6834,0.7435,0.4044)rgb=(0.7184,0.7411,0.3905)
        rgb=(0.7525,0.7384,0.3768)rgb=(0.7858,0.7356,0.3633)rgb=(0.8185,0.7327,0.3498)
        rgb=(0.8507,0.7299,0.336) rgb=(0.8824,0.7274,0.3217)rgb=(0.9139,0.7258,0.3063)
        rgb=(0.945,0.7261,0.2886) rgb=(0.9739,0.7314,0.2666)rgb=(0.9938,0.7455,0.2403)
        rgb=(0.999,0.7653,0.2164) rgb=(0.9955,0.7861,0.1967)rgb=(0.988,0.8066,0.1794)
        rgb=(0.9789,0.8271,0.1633)rgb=(0.9697,0.8481,0.1475)rgb=(0.9626,0.8705,0.1309)
        rgb=(0.9589,0.8949,0.1132)rgb=(0.9598,0.9218,0.0948)rgb=(0.9661,0.9514,0.0755)
        rgb=(0.9763,0.9831,0.0538)
        }
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        ,ymin=0,xmin=0,ymax=5,xmax=1
        ,colorbar
        ,colorbar style={ylabel=line slope}
        ]
        \foreach \m in {1,1.2,...,5} % you will need {1,...,5} here, but it looked so beautiful...
        {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[mesh,point meta=\m] {x*\m};}\temp}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As asked in your comment, here is a solution loading data from files:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_1.dat}
    0 0
    1 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_2.dat}
    0 0
    1 2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_3.dat}
    0 0
    1 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    ,ymin=0,xmin=0,ymax=5,xmax=1
    ,colorbar
    ,colorbar style={ylabel=line slope}
    ]
    \foreach \m in {1,...,3}
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[mesh,point meta=\m] table {data_\m.dat};}\temp}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's awesome.  i feel like i could find several uses for this.  you just solved a problem i didn't know i had...

Comment: The parula of Jake is missing its last value :P `rgb=(0.9763,0.9831,0.0538)`.

Comment: @Manuel you can trust nobody here... One day I will have to start coding my own stuff...

Comment: Really beautiful thanks!
What if in the for loop I want load data from tables?
Where in every table (lets say data_xx.dat) there is the data for a single curve?

Comment: @mrk_brn Please see my update. In future, please provide code (MWE) with your question. It is tedious for volunteers to set up the issue for you and to do all the typing. Maybe, for example, your tables look completely different from what I guessed above, and my answer is therefore worthless for you. Just as an advice for future postings.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi thank you very much!
I'm sorry for the MWE, usually I provide it, like in the first question, but this time i didn't. Sorry, my fault.