# How to set the color and width of your plotline using the third column in your table?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I would like to use the third column in my table to color code my plot**line** e.g. blue-red (-1 to 1) and set the width according to the absolute value of the third column (0 thick, 1 ultra thick (or more if possible)). Is this possible?

Here a MWE (taken from another question here on SE and reduced):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
    A       B       C
    0.0000  50.0000 -1.0000
    1.0000  49.9950 -0.8000
    2.0000  49.9800 -0.4000
    3.0000  49.9550 -0.0000
    4.0000  49.9201  0.2000
    5.0000  49.8752 -0.0000
    6.0000  49.8204 -0.1000
    7.0000  49.7556  0.0000
    8.0000  49.6810  0.4000
    9.0000  49.5966  0.8000
    10.0000 49.5023  1.0000  
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{test.dat}{\test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [smooth, ultra thick] table [x={A}, y={B}] {\test};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to start with. The option `smooth` is not possible. Maybe you manage this with help of the `\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}`; I did not. The topic about varying line width is treated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57896). I inserted the colormap parula (from an other [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232697) of me) as I like it, but you may leave this away of course.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.12
    ,colormap={parula}{%
        rgb=(0.2081,0.1663,0.5292)rgb=(0.2116,0.1898,0.5777)rgb=(0.2123,0.2138,0.627)
        rgb=(0.2081,0.2386,0.6771)rgb=(0.1959,0.2645,0.7279)rgb=(0.1707,0.2919,0.7792)
        rgb=(0.1253,0.3242,0.8303)rgb=(0.0591,0.3598,0.8683)rgb=(0.0117,0.3875,0.882)
        rgb=(0.006,0.4086,0.8828) rgb=(0.0165,0.4266,0.8786)rgb=(0.0329,0.443,0.872)
        rgb=(0.0498,0.4586,0.8641)rgb=(0.0629,0.4737,0.8554)rgb=(0.0723,0.4887,0.8467)
        rgb=(0.0779,0.504,0.8384) rgb=(0.0793,0.52,0.8312)  rgb=(0.0749,0.5375,0.8263)
        rgb=(0.0641,0.557,0.824)  rgb=(0.0488,0.5772,0.8228)rgb=(0.0343,0.5966,0.8199)
        rgb=(0.0265,0.6137,0.8135)rgb=(0.0239,0.6287,0.8038)rgb=(0.0231,0.6418,0.7913)
        rgb=(0.0228,0.6535,0.7768)rgb=(0.0267,0.6642,0.7607)rgb=(0.0384,0.6743,0.7436)
        rgb=(0.059,0.6838,0.7254) rgb=(0.0843,0.6928,0.7062)rgb=(0.1133,0.7015,0.6859)
        rgb=(0.1453,0.7098,0.6646)rgb=(0.1801,0.7177,0.6424)rgb=(0.2178,0.725,0.6193)
        rgb=(0.2586,0.7317,0.5954)rgb=(0.3022,0.7376,0.5712)rgb=(0.3482,0.7424,0.5473)
        rgb=(0.3953,0.7459,0.5244)rgb=(0.442,0.7481,0.5033) rgb=(0.4871,0.7491,0.484)
        rgb=(0.53,0.7491,0.4661)  rgb=(0.5709,0.7485,0.4494)rgb=(0.6099,0.7473,0.4337)
        rgb=(0.6473,0.7456,0.4188)rgb=(0.6834,0.7435,0.4044)rgb=(0.7184,0.7411,0.3905)
        rgb=(0.7525,0.7384,0.3768)rgb=(0.7858,0.7356,0.3633)rgb=(0.8185,0.7327,0.3498)
        rgb=(0.8507,0.7299,0.336) rgb=(0.8824,0.7274,0.3217)rgb=(0.9139,0.7258,0.3063)
        rgb=(0.945,0.7261,0.2886) rgb=(0.9739,0.7314,0.2666)rgb=(0.9938,0.7455,0.2403)
        rgb=(0.999,0.7653,0.2164) rgb=(0.9955,0.7861,0.1967)rgb=(0.988,0.8066,0.1794)
        rgb=(0.9789,0.8271,0.1633)rgb=(0.9697,0.8481,0.1475)rgb=(0.9626,0.8705,0.1309)
        rgb=(0.9589,0.8949,0.1132)rgb=(0.9598,0.9218,0.0948)rgb=(0.9661,0.9514,0.0755)
        rgb=(0.9763,0.9831,0.0538)
    }}

\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
    A       B       C
    0.0000  50.0000 -1.0000
    1.0000  49.9950 -0.8000
    2.0000  49.9800 -0.4000
    3.0000  49.9550 -0.0000
    4.0000  49.9201  0.2000
    5.0000  49.8752 -0.0000
    6.0000  49.8204 -0.1000
    7.0000  49.7556  0.0000
    8.0000  49.6810  0.4000
    9.0000  49.5966  0.8000
    10.0000 49.5023  1.0000  
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    ,colorbar
    ,colorbar style={ylabel=C}
    ,xlabel=A,ylabel=B
    ]
    \addplot [%
    ,mesh
    ,point meta=\thisrow{C}
    ,ultra thick
    ] table [x={A}, y={B}] {test.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]