# How to achieve equal colors for a marker's filling and edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, metadata

Consider the following example from the pgfplots manual p. 164:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[tiny]
        \addplot+[scatter] {sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[tiny]
        \addplot+[scatter,mark = o] {sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the edge color of the markers is darker than the fill color. If one uses a colormap and `point meta = ...` to color the scatter plot, then its always the **fill color** which is determined by `point meta = ...` - the edge color is somehow set to a darker color.

In case I use `mark = o` or `mark = x`, just the edges of the markers are plotted, in the darker color. But I'd like them to be as bright as in the filled case.

**So how can I make the marker edge color equal to its fill color?**

I couldn't find any command in the pgfplots manual to do so.

---

### More complex MWE

I'm using [**color coded plots**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232690/color-coded-plots-with-colorbar-in-pgfplots), which can be realized by abusing `\addplot[mesh]`. However the meta data which is used to plot the mesh does not affect the markers, they are black. So I used `\addplot[scatter]`, to get also color coded markers. I'd like to get circles, **but in the same color as the graph**. But as the circles are made by the darker edge color, it does not fit.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_1.dat}
    0 0
    1 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_2.dat}
    0 0
    1 2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_3.dat}
    0 0
    1 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    ,ymin=0,xmin=0,ymax=5,xmax=1,colorbar
    ]
    \foreach \m in {1,...,3}
        {\addplot[mesh,point meta=\m,mark=o] table {data_\m.dat};}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
        ,ymin=0,xmin=0,ymax=5,xmax=1,colorbar
        ]
        \foreach \m in {1,...,3}
            {\addplot[mesh,point meta=\m] table {data_\m.dat};}
        \foreach \m in {1,...,3}
                    {\addplot[scatter,point meta=\m, only marks, mark=o] table {data_\m.dat};}    

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The style of the markers in a `scatter` plot is determined using the key `scatter/use mapped color={draw=..., fill=...}` (see section 4.5.11 "Scatter Plots" in the manual). By default, it is set to `draw=mapped color!80!black,fill=mapped color`. In your case, you would want to set it to `scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_1.dat}
    0 0
    1 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_2.dat}
    0 0
    1 2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_3.dat}
    0 0
    1 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    ymin=0,xmin=0,ymax=5,xmax=1,colorbar
    ]
    \foreach \m in {1,...,3}
        {\addplot[mesh, scatter, scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color}, point meta=\m, mark=o] table {data_\m.dat};}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```