# Surface plot with custom color mixing: n-dimensional colormaps

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

The normal pgfplots-colormap is one-dimensional. It expects a single meta value and infers the corresponding color. However, instead of one meta value I have 3 meta values, each associated with a single value.

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that the three meta values (`n1`, `n2`, `n3`) are always positive and sum up to 1, then the color mixing rule is simple: `color = n1 * color1 + n2 * color2 + n3 * color3`.

Given this meta data (from a table) I would like to color the mesh with the appropriately mixed color.

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97523/pgfplots-color-a-3d-surf-using-arbitrary-rgb-colors) I have already figured out that the RGB values can be provided explicitly. But I am not able to get the formula right. In particular, I don't know how to access the RBG values of the defined colors.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{color1}{red}
\definecolor{color2}{cyan}
\definecolor{color3}{yellow}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[surf, mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
            point meta/symbolic={\thisrow{n1}, \thisrow{n2}, \thisrow{n3} } % problematic line
            % how do I mix the colors here so that color = n1 * color1 + n2 * color2 + n3 * color3?
           ] table[] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The data file `data.csv` contains something like this:

```
x,y,z,n1,n2,n3
-1.0,-1.0,0,0.243910357114819,0.2666555209251139,0.4894341219600671
-0.5,-1.0,0,0.3013791690628364,0.2152633649632925,0.48335746597387114
0.0,-1.0,0,0.5021192190297844,0.16757485484227622,0.3303059261279394
0.5,-1.0,0,0.5979647407883067,0.14009437103777442,0.2619408881739188

-1.0,-0.5,0,0.164292920913273,0.2655366172800358,0.5701704618066912
-0.5,-0.5,0,0.1355599513531367,0.2040615139888475,0.6603785346580158
0.0,-0.5,0,0.4083574985065873,0.2049743531246625,0.3866681483687502
0.5,-0.5,0,0.4880958726415202,0.2436859445670927,0.2682181827913871

-1.0,0.0,0,0.13994145285914186,0.26041474337409753,0.5996438037667606
-0.5,0.0,0,0.08883801351075463,0.19202791600642005,0.7191340704828253
0.0,0.0,0,0.1290235911491401,0.22620482004695425,0.6447715888039056
0.5,0.0,0,0.1901399752789048,0.49178772678672855,0.31807229793436664

-1.0,0.5,0,0.15879820629696065,0.2619254086260544,0.579276385076985
-0.5,0.5,0,0.11257406503995221,0.18855240164294096,0.6988735333171068
0.0,0.5,0,0.09915126016628552,0.243518553933322,0.6573301859003925
0.5,0.5,0,0.0914288508897056,0.5882997108532986,0.3202714382569958
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is my solution to this interesting problem:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{my-data.csv}
x   y   z   n1  n2  n3
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0

0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

% Each point of the plot will be assigned a color which is a mix of these
% three colors according to the weights given by columns n1, n2 and n3 of the
% data point, respectively.
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.1,1.0,0.5}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,1.0}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1.0,0.6,0.3}

% Extract the color components into 9 macros so that accessing each component
% when drawing the plot is as fast as possible. The target control sequences
% are \color<num>r, \color<num>g and \color<num>b where <num> is I, II or III
% (corresponding to the three colors 'color1', 'color2' and 'color3').
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__minze_color_index_int
\seq_new:N \l__minze_color_components_seq

\clist_map_inline:nn { color1, color2, color3 }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l__minze_color_index_int
    \extractcolorspecs {#1} { \l_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpb_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__minze_color_components_seq { , } \l_tmpb_tl

    \clist_map_inline:nn { r, g, b }
      {
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l__minze_color_components_seq \l_tmpa_tl
        \cs_new_nopar:cpx
          { color \int_to_Roman:n { \l__minze_color_index_int } ##1 }
          { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$, z label style={rotate=-90}]
  \addplot3 [
    surf, mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
    patch type=bilinear, shader=interp,
    point meta/symbolic={
      (\thisrow{n1}*\colorIr + \thisrow{n2}*\colorIIr + \thisrow{n3}*\colorIIIr)
        / (\thisrow{n1} + \thisrow{n2} + \thisrow{n3}),
      (\thisrow{n1}*\colorIg + \thisrow{n2}*\colorIIg + \thisrow{n3}*\colorIIIg)
        / (\thisrow{n1} + \thisrow{n2} + \thisrow{n3}),
      (\thisrow{n1}*\colorIb + \thisrow{n2}*\colorIIb + \thisrow{n3}*\colorIIIb)
        / (\thisrow{n1} + \thisrow{n2} + \thisrow{n3})
    },
    ] table[x=x, y=y, z=z] {my-data.csv};

  % Color legend
  \begin{scope}[nodes={minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.25cm,
                       inner sep=0, draw=black, right, label distance=2mm}]
    \coordinate (p) at (rel axis cs:0.3,0.5,1.1);
    \path (p)
      node[fill=color1, label=right:{color 1}] (node 1) {}
      ++(axis direction cs:0,0,-0.15)
      node[fill=color2, label=right:{color 2}] (node 2) {}
      ++(axis direction cs:0,0,-0.15)
      node[fill=color3, label=right:{color 3}] (node 3) {};
  \end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

This conforms to the input data from file `my-data.csv`:

- The point at (0,0,0) has (n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>) = (0,0,0) → black;
- The point at (1,0,0) has (n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>) = (1,0,0) → custom color `color1`;
- The point at (0,1,0) has (n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>) = (0,1,0) → custom color `color2`;
- The point at (1,1,1) has (n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>) = (0,0,1) → custom color `color3`.

Every point of the mesh is assigned a color which is a mix of colors `color1`, `color2` and `color3` according to weights respectively given by the `n1`, `n2` and `n3` columns for the data point.

It is not necessary to ensure that n1 + n2 + n3 = 1, because my code divides by n1 + n2 + n3 in the appropriate place.

If we take your data file with modified *z* coordinates (yours are all equal), use `col sep=comma` in the `table` options from the `\addplot3 [...] table[...]` call, and `clip=false` in the `axis` options (because this time, I draw the legend outside the axis and I don't want it to be clipped away), we obtain:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x,y,z,n1,n2,n3
-1.0,-1.0,0,0.243910357114819,0.2666555209251139,0.4894341219600671
-0.5,-1.0,0,0.3013791690628364,0.2152633649632925,0.48335746597387114
0.0,-1.0,0,0.5021192190297844,0.16757485484227622,0.3303059261279394
0.5,-1.0,0,0.5979647407883067,0.14009437103777442,0.2619408881739188

-1.0,-0.5,0.2,0.164292920913273,0.2655366172800358,0.5701704618066912
-0.5,-0.5,0.2,0.1355599513531367,0.2040615139888475,0.6603785346580158
0.0,-0.5,0.2,0.4083574985065873,0.2049743531246625,0.3866681483687502
0.5,-0.5,0.2,0.4880958726415202,0.2436859445670927,0.2682181827913871

-1.0,0.0,0.9,0.13994145285914186,0.26041474337409753,0.5996438037667606
-0.5,0.0,0.9,0.08883801351075463,0.19202791600642005,0.7191340704828253
0.0,0.0,0.9,0.1290235911491401,0.22620482004695425,0.6447715888039056
0.5,0.0,0.9,0.1901399752789048,0.49178772678672855,0.31807229793436664

-1.0,0.5,1.2,0.15879820629696065,0.2619254086260544,0.579276385076985
-0.5,0.5,1.6,0.11257406503995221,0.18855240164294096,0.6988735333171068
0.0,0.5,1.6,0.09915126016628552,0.243518553933322,0.6573301859003925
0.5,0.5,1.4,0.0914288508897056,0.5882997108532986,0.3202714382569958
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

% Each point of the plot will be assigned a color which is a mix of these
% three colors according to the weights given by columns n1, n2 and n3 of the
% data point, respectively.
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.1,1.0,0.5}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,1.0}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1.0,0.6,0.3}

% Extract the color components into 9 macros so that accessing each component
% when drawing the plot is as fast as possible. The target control sequences
% are \color<num>r, \color<num>g and \color<num>b where <num> is I, II or III
% (corresponding to the three colors 'color1', 'color2' and 'color3').
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__minze_color_index_int
\seq_new:N \l__minze_color_components_seq

\clist_map_inline:nn { color1, color2, color3 }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l__minze_color_index_int
    \extractcolorspecs {#1} { \l_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpb_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__minze_color_components_seq { , } \l_tmpb_tl

    \clist_map_inline:nn { r, g, b }
      {
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l__minze_color_components_seq \l_tmpa_tl
        \cs_new_nopar:cpx
          { color \int_to_Roman:n { \l__minze_color_index_int } ##1 }
          { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$, z label style={rotate=-90},
             clip=false]
  \addplot3 [
    surf, mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
    patch type=bilinear, shader=interp,
    point meta/symbolic={
      (\thisrow{n1}*\colorIr + \thisrow{n2}*\colorIIr + \thisrow{n3}*\colorIIIr)
        / (\thisrow{n1} + \thisrow{n2} + \thisrow{n3}),
      (\thisrow{n1}*\colorIg + \thisrow{n2}*\colorIIg + \thisrow{n3}*\colorIIIg)
        / (\thisrow{n1} + \thisrow{n2} + \thisrow{n3}),
      (\thisrow{n1}*\colorIb + \thisrow{n2}*\colorIIb + \thisrow{n3}*\colorIIIb)
        / (\thisrow{n1} + \thisrow{n2} + \thisrow{n3})
    },
    ] table[x=x, y=y, z=z, col sep=comma] {data.csv};

  % Color legend
  \begin{scope}[nodes={minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.25cm,
                       inner sep=0, draw=black, right, label distance=2mm}]
    \coordinate (p) at (rel axis cs:-0.4,0.5,1.1);
    \path (p)
      node[fill=color1, label=right:{color 1}] (node 1) {}
      ++(axis direction cs:0,0,-0.15)
      node[fill=color2, label=right:{color 2}] (node 2) {}
      ++(axis direction cs:0,0,-0.15)
      node[fill=color3, label=right:{color 3}] (node 3) {};
  \end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]